# How to use ArcGIS API for Javascript print task to create a legend for dynamically rendered layer

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, printing

I am using v 3.11 of the ArcGIS API for Javascript and executing the PrintTask to generate a printable pdf of a web map. The map has a couple of Dynamic Map Service Layers that are dynamically rendered, i.e. the user can control the layer symbology based on various inputs.

When I execute the PrintTask, the dynamically rendered layers do appear on the printable pdf map. But, I can't get a legend for those dynamic layers to appear on the pdf.  I have tried a couple different approaches:

1) I have excluded the legendLayer array from the 'layoutOptions' object. I was hoping that would automatically generate a legend for all layers on the map, as suggested by the documentation. A legend does appear with the non-dynamic operational layers present, but not the dynamically rendered layers

2) I have created a legendLayer object specific to the dynamically rendered layers, like the code below, but still the layer doesn't appear in the legend.

```
var printTemplate = new PrintTemplate();  
var legendLayers = [];  
var legendLayer = new LegendLayer();  
legendLayer.layerId = "dynLayer_0";  
legendLayer.subLayerIds = [0];  
legendLayers.push(legendLayer);  
printTemplate.layoutOptions = { "titleText": title, "scalebarUnit": this._localMap.getAppConfig().printing.scalebarUnit, "legendLayers": legendLayers};
```

Any suggestions on how i can get my dynamically rendered layers to appear in the map legend?

(This same question is posted on the Esri discussion forum [here](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/117321))